Securing an angular/c# application with keycloak and nginx
(It is possible I need keycloak pro for this.  Not sure.)

I am running keycloak as a service on my fedora box.

It is listening on ports 5006/5007 - 5007 for the admin console.

the admin console should be accessible only from adresses 10.9.8.0/24 and 127.0.0.1

any communication 'behind' my nginx proxy should be http.




+----------------------+
| (Angular)app/browser |
+----------------------+
           |
         https
           |
   +------------------+
   |    example.com   |
   |      NGINX       |
   |    10.9.8.1      |<------ http -----+
   +------------------+                  |
                                         |
   +---------------+                     |
   |   Keycloak    |<-- authentication --+
   +---------------+                     |
           ^                             |
           |                             |
     authorisation                       |
           |                             |
           +------------- Requests ------+---------------+
           |                 |                           |
           v                 v                           v
   +----------------+  +--------------------+  +--------------------+
   |   C# SignalR   |  |  C# web services   |  |      Angular       |
   +----------------+  +--------------------+  +--------------------+



my nginx is configured:


# Proxy for the authentication server (public)
location /auth/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5006/auth/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}

# Proxy for the admin interface
location /admin/ {
    allow 10.9.8.0/24;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5007/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_buffering off;   # Ensure real-time responses from Keycloak
}



and keyCloak is like this
feature=hostname:v1

# Configuration for the authentication server (public)
http-enabled=true
http-host=127.0.0.1
http-port=5006

# Configuration for the admin interface
http-management-port=5007

# Hostname settings
hostname=example.com
hostname-url=https://example.com/auth
hostname-admin-url=https://example.com/admin



When I browse to https://example.com/admin/ (from a node on my 10.9.8.0/24 network) all I see is a white page with the text 'Keycloak Management Interface'. tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log shows no errors and the network trace in chrome shows a single 200 response.
https://example.com/auth/, on the other hand, shows a page with the keycloak logo and a message We are sorry... Page not found and a 404 error in the network trace.
I am missing something, I just don't know what it is.
